# Aptana 3 is not starting and only says "An error has occurred. See the log file."

Tags: aptana3

I have checked the log file and see the following: (an ideas how to resolve?)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-10-22 09:44:40.920
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (427).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/dlpage-css/database/setup/countries.txt' not found.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2503)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2251)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: I am still unable to get Aptana to run.  Would changing the version of Java that Aptana is using help?  If so, how do you change it?

Comment: Ok as a quick test I renamed the jre directory to old_jre and copied my 7u9 jre directory under AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3 and it fails with a server/jvm.dll error.

Comment: Here is what finally worked:
It looks like your eclipse crashed sometime before and is unable to restore the workspace (the metadata stored by the eclipse might be corrupted).

Try using a new workspace. To force the workspace window prompt you need to change the settings in <Eclipse_root_dir>\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and set SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG to true


You import all your projects to the new workspace.
Found at this thread: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156204/

Answer (score 9):

This just happened to me again and at the worst time possible.

I really didn't want to have to rebuild the whole workspace but I found this answer and it worked!

> For anyone interested, I had the exact same problem and deleting the
>   file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap did the trick
>   for me.

This file is located in your broken workspace's folder.

From: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/156204/734920/#msg_734920

Comment: Very nice solution. My workspace was my home directory, and this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: Glad it helped! That said, I have since moved to SublimeText and I don't think I'll be looking back - bought a license after two weeks of delighted use.

Comment: Yes this does the trick but it breaks the editor. So I finished simply removing the .history, .root, .safetable folders and the .snap file inside of the org.eclipse.core.resources folder, somehow this didn't broke my editor. Thank you.

Comment: Removing the .snap file allowed Eclipse to open. Project gone from PackageExplorer, previously open classes reporting 'File Does Not Exist.' I created a new workspace, imported my project (General>Existing Project Into Workspace>Choose the source folder) and all is fixed without further deleting of files necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting/renaming the Workspace folder (eg. Documents\Aptana 3 Studio Workspace), that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I increased the -Xms and -Xmx values in STS.ini and it solved the problem.
New Values:
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m