# Can't restart Aptana Studio 3

Tags: linux, aptana, workspace, linux-mint

Using Aptana Studio 3 I queued a lot of new projects -> "upgrade existing folder as a new project" and closed a bunch of them afterwards. While the operations were running I edited a file but when I tried to save, a pop up window notified me of the list of operations queued, building workspace on top of it.

After waiting half an hour "building workspace" was still stuck at 80% and I killed the process. Now Aptana won't start at all, I just get a little grey window with a default look and feel and the Aptana Studio 3 title which can't be closed with the standard cross icon.

I'm working on a Linux Mint machine.

I found an Aptana log file, it is quite verbose but I think in this excerpt there is the key to the solution:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-01-09 19:35:58.829
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-09 19:35:59.250
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (427).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
```

it goes on with other lines like the last one until:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/lectiosbusiness/funzioni/sql.php' not found.
```

Then more of the lines beginning with "at org.eclipse"

Comment: did you really kill the process? maybe an instance of the program still running

Comment: yeah, killed and restarted the whole machine. My guess it's because at start Aptana tries to build workspace and get stuck onto something.

Comment: i don't think a software like aptana "crashed" just for editing and closing projects, try this open aptana and run this `# killall -15 aptanastudio` or whatever pid have aptana and check

Comment: that gives me aptanastudio: no process found. But with ps -ef | grep Aptana i get 4379  2191  2 17:23 ? 00:00:02 /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reach a partial solution: i've searched for the

```
Tree element '/path/filename.php' not found.
```

and i found this topic:
[Aptana 3 is not starting and only says "An error has occurred. See the log file."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015449/aptana-3-is-not-starting-and-only-says-an-error-has-occurred-see-the-log-file)

which refers to:
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/156204/734920/#msg_734920

and they say to delete .snap file locate at

```
yourworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

my workspace is in sync to dropbox so i tried to go back to previous versions but that didn't worked and i ended up deleting it. Now aptana starts but i have to remake all of my projects and connections.